# Copy Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I want to copy multiple cloud functions from one project to another GCP project. Please help me. My main goal is to use a script to replicate a GCP project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't copy resource. The easiest way is to have the code in a git repository and to redeploy the code in a new project.

Comment: Yes, the git way is the only way for now. Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere